# java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset during file unzip in java

Tags: java

`org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile` throws exception `java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset`
during the execution of this line of code `zipFile = new ZipFile(new File(zipfile));` As soon as I reduce the size of zipfile, the problem does not comes. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing which could happen with a corrupt zip file (and a bug that trusts some data it shouldn't).

Comment: The file that i am unzipping is not iN UTF format.If the file was corrupted,may be it should not have been unzip when used with RAR .But,it is not the case.It is unzip with RAR.

Comment: Just because it unzips with RAR does not neccessarily mean its a valid zip :)

Comment: @abishkar: Are you able to upload the zip file somewhere else so that we can have a look?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, @ Duncan The file that i am trying to unzip is compressed in .lzh format.May be it is the problem of format.It works fine now,when it is in zip format
,but when it is in .lzh format,the same exception is thrown.

Comment: @abishkar: Um, yes. LZH isn't Zip. The RAR tool may well be able to handle both, but something which is designed to only read zip files won't...